# Como calcular um valor em um determinado range?

Tags: javascript, matemática, lógica

Eu tenho de fazer o seguinte cálculo:
Eu tenho um número de entrada (digamos que 1.3), que está no meu range A, que vai de 0 a 3, e preciso de um valor correspondente no range b (que é inversamente proporcional), que vai de 3 a 1.
**Como eu posso calcular, partindo de dados dois ranges, um valor do range B que correspanda ao valor de entrada que está no range A?**
Exemplo:
Range A: (0 - 3)
Range B: (3 - 1)
Valor passado do Range A: 1.5
Valor esperado do retorno: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está buscando algo inversamente proporcional. É mais matemática que programação, mas colocando isso em código:

Considerando:

- A_max o valor máximo do range A (3)
- A_min o valor mínimo do range A (0)
- B_max o valor máximo do range B (3)
- B_min o valor mínimo do range B (1)

Temos:

`output = ((input - A_min)*(B_max - B_min)) / (A_max - A_min) + B_min;`

Comment: obrigado, amigo, resolveu o problema. (so tenho de lembrar de inverter os valores maximo e minimo de B pra ter o resultado correto, mas ja ajudou demais)

Comment: Eu não entendi como que os ranges estavam dispostos (se era num Array ordenado ou não), então decidi não complicar o código e deixar mais aberto para a sua implementação. Mas fico feliz em ter te ajudado =)